# ASP.Net VB - Linq to XML group by child element value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I need to group all values based on child element value. Below is example of my XML

```
<Matchday date="2016-05-09">
   <Match id="1288348">
      <Home id="13" name="club1"/>
      <Away id="14" name="club2"/>
      <Information>
         <country>England</country>
      </Information>
   </Match>
   <Match id="1288349">
      <Home id="15" name="club3"/>
      <Away id="16" name="club4"/>
      <Information>
         <country>England</country>
      </Information>
   </Match>
   <Match id="1288350">
      <Home id="17" name="club5"/>
      <Away id="18" name="club6"/>
      <Information>
         <country>Italy</country>
      </Information>
   </Match>
   <Match id="1288351">
      <Home id="19" name="club7"/>
      <Away id="20" name="club8"/>
      <Information>
         <country>Spain</country>
      </Information>
   </Match>
</Matchday>
```

I want to group by country, so the result will be like this :

```
England
   1288348
   1288349

Italy
   1288350

Spain
   1288351
```

How to do this using vb linq to xml query from code-behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
Dim result = data.Elements("Match") _
                 .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Element("Information").Element("country").Value)

For Each r As IGrouping(Of String, XElement) In result
    Console.WriteLine(r.Key)
    For Each m As XElement In r
        Console.WriteLine(m.@id)
    Next
Next
```

where `data` is an `XElement` declared as follow :

```
Dim data As XElement = <Matchday date="2016-05-09">
                       <Match id="1288348">
                           <Home id="13" name="club1"/>
                           <Away id="14" name="club2"/>
                           <Information>
                               <country>England</country>
                           </Information>
                       </Match>
                       <Match id="1288349">
                           <Home id="15" name="club3"/>
                           <Away id="16" name="club4"/>
                           <Information>
                               <country>England</country>
                           </Information>
                       </Match>
                       <Match id="1288350">
                           <Home id="17" name="club5"/>
                           <Away id="18" name="club6"/>
                           <Information>
                               <country>Italy</country>
                           </Information>
                       </Match>
                       <Match id="1288351">
                           <Home id="19" name="club7"/>
                           <Away id="20" name="club8"/>
                           <Information>
                               <country>Spain</country>
                           </Information>
                       </Match>
                   </Matchday>
```

and the output is as follow :

```
England
1288348
1288349
Italy
1288350
Spain
1288351
```

Comment: thanks, you code works great but I had to fix your query a little bit. This is the working query :   Dim matchGroup = From mG In xe.Descendants.Elements("Matchday").Elements("Match").GroupBy(Function(x) x.Element("Information").Element("country").Value)
                       Select mG

Comment: What is `xe` in your code? If it is an `XDocument`, use `xe.Root` instead of `xe.Descendants()`. The former would be far more efficient.

Comment: I forgot this,  Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("exporter.xml"))